# Php application in a Microsoft Network

Tags: php, apache, account

I am developing a php application to be used in a corporate Microsoft network. I do not know if I can use Apache.

I need to set permissions according to the Microsoft account currently running. Each user has his personal account. How can I check, in a secure way, which user is connected?

Comment: In that case I would consider to take a look on IIS, makes life much easier - if possible. (In case you mean with account an AD account)

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about. Could you show me any example?

Answer (score 0):

However the answer was to use LDAP!